# install scoop using powershell without admin rights

Tags: powershell, scoop-installer, python-scoop

Can I execute `Set-ExecutionPolicy` in PowerShell 7.4.10 without admin rights to install scoop?

```
PS C:\Windows\System32> PS C:\> Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy remotesigned -Scope CurrentUser -InvokeRestMethod -Uri https://get.scoop.sh | Invoke-Expression -Force
Get-Process: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Set-ExecutionPolicy'.
```

Comment: You cannot bypass [UAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/application-security/application-control/user-account-control/how-it-works) if that's your question.

Comment: Did you copy-paste the command from somewhere? `PS C:\>` is not part of the code you'll want to run, it's the prompt (like `PS C:\Windows\System32>` on your own machine)

Comment: With some reading I figured that one out

Comment: @rivka-12 So you may update your question with clarifying details and get it re-opened and then post your findings as an answer to your own question and help other future readers or you simply delete the question.  ‍♂️